# "undefined package " by Ballerina with kubernetes within Visual Code

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, ballerina

[Ballerina extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ballerina.ballerina) was installed successfully in visual code. 
Also I configured `ballerina.home` to point to the installed package

```
ballerina.home = "/Library/Ballerina/ballerina-0.975.1"
```

Visual code is linting correctly. However, when I introduced `@kubernetes:*` annotations:

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/log;

@kubernetes:Deployment {
    enableLiveness: true,
    image: "ballerina/ballerina-platform",
    name: "ballerina-abdennour-demo"
}

@kubernetes:Service {
    serviceType: "NodePort",
    name: "ballerina-abdennour-demo"

}
service<http:Service> hello bind { port: 9090 } {
    sayHello (endpoint caller, http:Request request) {
        http:Response res = new;
        res.setPayload("Hello World from Ballerina Service");
        caller ->respond(res) but { error e => log:printError("Error sending response", err = e)};

    }
}
```

VisualCode reports an error :

```
undefined package "kubernetes"
undefined annotation "Deployment"
```

Nevertheless, I have minikube up and running, and I don't know if I need another extension, so VisualCode can detect running clusters?

Or is it a package that is missing and should be installed inside Ballerina SDK/ Platform?

### UPDATE

I am running `ballerina build file.bal`, and I can see this errors :

[image]

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4):

Solved! Just add the `import` instruction at the beginning of the file

```
import ballerinax/kubernetes;
```

Note, it is `ballerinax/kubernetes` and not `ballerina/kubernetes` (add `x`)

Answer (score 2):

[The fine manual](https://ballerina.io/learn/how-to-deploy-and-run-ballerina-programs/#kubernetes-based-deployment) very clearly shows that one must import the kubernetes package just like any other. I agree it's a bad error message on their part, so feel free to submit a bug in their repo explaining how to improve your experience

Comment: Thank you @Matthew Daniel for your time. The issue was resolved : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51341011/747579

Comment: Yes, Ballerina is still in early stages and feel free to report any concerns that come across. And PRs are always welcome as this an open source project.